# Jquery multiple modals plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I'm using [this simple jquery plugin](http://vast-eng.github.io/jquery-popup-overlay/) for modal popups but it doesn't have a function for multiple popups so I'm trying to make my own.

First I added unique indexes to the buttons that open the modal and the modal divs. The HTML is created dynamically.

```
<button class="my_modal_open" id="1">Open modal</button>
<div id="my_modal" class="1" style="display:none;margin:1em;">
    <a href="#" class="my_modal_close" style="float:right;padding:0 0.4em;">×</a>
    Modal Content
</div>

<button class="my_modal_open" id="2">Open modal</button>
<div id="my_modal" class="2" style="display:none;margin:1em;">
    <a href="#" class="my_modal_close" style="float:right;padding:0 0.4em;">×</a>
    Modal Content
</div>

<button class="my_modal_open" id="3">Open modal</button>
<div id="my_modal" class="3" style="display:none;margin:1em;">
    <a href="#" class="my_modal_close" style="float:right;padding:0 0.4em;">×</a>
    Modal Content
</div>
```

And then I modified the js to open modals by appropriate index.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.my_modal_open').click( function() {
        $('#my_modal').css('display','none'); //added
        var open_id = $(this).attr('id'); //added
        $('#my_modal.' + open_id).popup(); //changed to get div id and class               
  });
});
```

This works but the modals open only once. As a fix I tried adding

`$('#my_modal').css('display','block');`

after the `popup()` function which works but the modal doesn't display in the right position, the second time.

Please share any suggestions. Hopefully someone used this plugin before.

Comment: jquery-ui does modals just fine.  Just sayin'

Comment: @KiranRuthR, I'm opening them by unique indexes not id

Comment: @PaulTomblin yes but I need responsive modals and not sure if jqeury ui has that. And i really need a light weight js

Comment: jquery-ui does modals.  It doesn't care how you style them.  And you're already using jquery, so "light weight" is already kind of out the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at other libraries like jQuery UI or Twitter Bootstrap, since they have already solved this problem. If you want to roll your own, I would change your approach slightly.

Add an attribute to the buttons which stores the ID of the modal dialog you want to show. In the example below I called it "data-modal-id". When you click the button, get the value of that attribute and look up the modal with that ID and show it:

**HTML**

```
<button class="my_modal_open" data-modal-id="1">Open modal</button>
<div id="1" style="display:none;margin:1em;">
    <a href="#" class="my_modal_close" style="float:right;padding:0 0.4em;">×</a>
    Modal Content
</div>

<button class="my_modal_open" data-modal-id="2">Open modal</button>
<div id="2"style="display:none;margin:1em;">
    <a href="#" class="my_modal_close" style="float:right;padding:0 0.4em;">×</a>
    Modal Content
</div>

<button class="my_modal_open" data-modal-id="3">Open modal</button>
<div id="3" style="display:none;margin:1em;">
    <a href="#" class="my_modal_close" style="float:right;padding:0 0.4em;">×</a>
    Modal Content
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.my_modal_open').click(function () {
        $('#' + $(this).data("modal-id")).popup()
    });
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V3z6f/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use fadeIn() and fadeOut().

Example

Create something like

`<div class="my_modal_background"></div>`

where in css

```
.my_modal_background{ background:#000; position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%; z-indez:0 }

.my_modal_open div{ z-index:1; }
```

And your Jquery must be like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.my_modal_open').click(function () {
        $(this).children('div').fadeIn();
        $('.my_modal_background').fadeIn();
    });
});
```