# Multiple modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add multiple modal windows to my page, but don't manage very well at it. Currently I'm using code below and I would need to modify it to be usable with multiple modals as well.

HTML:

```
<div class="modal">
<div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="modal--contents modal--transition">
    <a class="modal--close" href="#"><img src="/images/icons/modal/close.png">Close</a>
    <h2>How to install on Windows</h2>
    <div class="instructions">
        <div class="instructions-single">
            <img src="/images/placeholders/step.png" alt="Step 1">
            <h3>Step 1</h3>
            <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="instructions-single">
            <img src="/images/placeholders/step.png" alt="Step 2">
            <h3>Step 2</h3>
            <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="instructions-single">
            <img src="/images/placeholders/step.png" alt="Step 3">
            <h3>Step 3</h3>
            <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="overlay--trigger btn"><img src="/images/icons/download/help_icon.png" alt="Help">How to install</a>
```

JS:

```
var modal = $('.modal');

$( ".btn" ).on( "click", function() {
  $( modal ).toggleClass('modal--show');
});

$( ".overlay" ).on( "click", function() {
  $( modal ).toggleClass('modal--show');
});

$( ".modal--close" ).on( "click", function() {
  $( modal ).toggleClass('modal--show');
});
```

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: So where is the button, and how would it relate to the different modals ?

Comment: I tried to change just classes and duplicate the code, but modals didn't work. How could I make this to work with many modals, and preferably extendable.

Comment: I added the trigger there, sorry.

Comment: well yeah, if you change the classes the JS isn't going to work anymore. Do you plan on having multiple modals on the same page? cause if not you can just reuse that HTML on any page you want.

Comment: Yes exactly, I have multiple modals on same page.

Comment: Instead of $(modal) use modal. everywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using multiple modals on one page I would do something like this:

where ever you have a `.btn` you want to trigger a specific modal, add a `data-attr` to it like so:

```
<div class="btn" data-modal-type="type1">
```

or

```
<div class="btn" data-modal-type="type2">
```

and I would add maybe an `id` of the same to the html for each modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="type1">
```

You should pull that type on click and use it to trigger the proper modal:

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
   var Type = $(this).data("modal-type");
   $("#"+Type).toggleClass('modal--show');
});
```

That way you're more specific about the modal you are triggering.

[**SAMPLE FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ghj35uet/)

To be honest though, the more efficient way of doing this is my using `ajax` to dynamically load a separate file with the corresponding info when you click. That way you would have just one modal script and swap out the info.

**UPDATE**

This is what I mean based off of your codePen:

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByLwgM)

Comment: Thanks! I quite didn't get how I would keep the animation and other stuff. Can you check this CodePen? http://codepen.io/aleksitappura/pen/bNwowK

Comment: @aleksitappura I added a new CodePen

Comment: Yes, now it seems logical. Thank you and SO community!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$(modal)` use `modal.` everywhere

```
var modal = $('.modal');
 $( ".btn" ).on( "click", function() {
 modal.toggleClass('modal--show');
});

$( ".overlay" ).on( "click", function() {
  modal.toggleClass('modal--show');
});

$( ".modal--close" ).on( "click", function() {
  modal.toggleClass('modal--show');
});
```

Comment: that's part of the issue but i think the larger issue here is triggering a modal when there are multiple ones on the same page

Comment: Yes, I would want to make it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17636099/2544086 but I couldn't.